# How to customize which terminal is used by the "Git Bash Here" command of msysgit's shell extension?

Tags: git, version-control, msysgit

The default cmd.exe is horrible, I'd like to use, say, the "Console" shell.

Comment: See also this question: http://superuser.com/questions/172520/git-bash-here-in-console2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The registry key used to launch that cmd.exe is:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\git_shell\command
```

It contains (on my Windows7 installation):

```
"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe" /c "pushd "%1" && "C:\Prog\Git\1.6.5.1\bin\sh.exe" --login -i"
```

So you could change that entry by any other console you want.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was seeking for.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Git-1.7.6-preview20110708

You can edit the Git Bash.vbs file located in C:\Program Files\Git:

Here is my full Git Bash.vbs file

```
Option Explicit

Dim shell : Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim fso : Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim gitdir : gitdir = Left(WScript.ScriptFullName,InStrRev(WScript.ScriptFullName,"\"))
Dim bash : bash = fso.BuildPath(gitdir, "bin\sh.exe")
Dim temp : temp = fso.GetSpecialFolder(2) ' Temporary folder
Dim linkfile : linkfile = fso.BuildPath(temp, fso.GetTempName() & ".lnk")

Dim link : Set link = shell.CreateShortCut(linkfile)
link.TargetPath = bash
link.Arguments = "--login -i"
link.WindowStyle = 1
If WScript.Arguments.Length > 0 Then link.WorkingDirectory = WScript.Arguments(0)
link.Save

Dim app : Set app = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
If WScript.Arguments.Length=1 Then
    app.ShellExecute "C:\Program Files\Console2\Console.exe", " -t ""Git Bash"" -d """ & WScript.Arguments(0) & """"
Else
    app.ShellExecute "C:\Program Files\Console2\Console.exe", " -t ""Git Bash"""
End If
```

Comment: tried this in Git 1.7.10-preview20120409 but had not effect on the shell extension commands (which use git-cheetah)

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry to say that if you are using `git-cheetah` this seems to be impossible for now. I found this question while looking for an answer so I thought I would put the results of my findings here.

`git-cheetah` looks up the the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Git-Cheetah\PathToMsys` and executes `sh` from that path.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/) as your terminal there is no need to change the registry. You can configure it all from within ConEmu as described [here](https://superuser.com/a/454381/291067)